# Why is 'Line Dissolve' producing different output than 'Dissolve' from Ftools?

Tags: saga, ftools

I'm curious if anyone can explain the strange effects I'm seeing from the SAGA 'Line Dissolve' tool. I have a ton of line features that had previously been 'exploded' (which is a necessary step), and now need to be rejoined together so that 'Create Points Along Lines' works properly.

Using the Vector > Geoprocessing > Dissolve tool takes an ungodly amount of time to process (I'm talking hours for a single dataset, which is much too long), but creates expected results after adding the points along the dissolved lines. When I run the 'Line Dissolve' tool from the processing toolbox, it takes about 5 seconds to process, but the points along the lines are sporadic and seemingly placed at random (see attached screenshots).

Points along lines after Vector > Geoprocessing > Dissolve:
[image]

Points along lines after "Line Dissolve":
[image]

Comment: When joining the lines with Dissolve, are you using a Field to identify which lines should be joined together?

Comment: @klewis yes, using the field 'DN', of which all lines have the same value (255)

Comment: After Dissolve, do you have a single multi-part line?

Comment: @klewis yes, with both Dissolve and Dissolve Line

Comment: Geoprocessing uses actual gdal version, fw-tools uses very old version of gdal. maybe thats the reason for the differences...

Comment: Are you confident the lines don't repeat back on themselves? I've seen this before when the line switches direction.

Comment: see my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/292105/55203) - as per @Fezter suggestion. This clumping can be due to direction switches between successive segments.