# QChainage only works on first part of merged line

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qchainage

I'm trying to merge a number of lines into a single line for chainage purposes. Each individual line is created using OpenRouteService, then merged into a longer continuous shape using Edit > Merge Selected Features. However, when I then run QChainage on the resulting merged line, the chainage stops at the end of the first line, even though I'm using the merged shape.

See the screenshot below for an example. I've merged two lines, one north of Boyle, the other starting in Boyle and heading south. The chainage only appears on the northern section of the merged line.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I've run to the same problem several times. I've usually used Dissolve tool from geoprocessing menu after which this behaviour can be observed.

Comment: Using Join multiple lines-plugin fixed the issue for me as per in this more or less related post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292105/qchainage-doesnt-place-points-evenly-along-dissolved-lines Perhaps someone who has more insight could explain the logic behind this behaviour.