# Create equidistant points along line network?

Tags: point, qgis-3, line, algorithm, network

I am trying to create points at every X meters along a set of lines that represent a network. As suggested in [QChainage doesn't place points evenly along dissolved lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292105/qchainage-doesnt-place-points-evenly-along-dissolved-lines) I managed to this successfully with the help of `Join Multiple Lines` and `QChainage` plugins.

The problem is that the lines are not thought to be a continuous segment and therefore when running `Join Multiple Lines` I end up having extra lines to join truncated segments into a continuous one, and then `QChainage` counts the length of that when adding points. With this method I have points being too close or outside of the original lines, so it is not valid.

So a solution would involve considering all the line features as one, so then the chainage would place the points correctly. But I don't think this is fundamentally possible in GIS without adding extra lines to connect them all?

What's the right approach to this? Should I convert this into a network and perhaps run another tool? Is there any tool that can do that in a network based approach? I am happy to try python solutions too.

[image: Original Lines][image: After running Join Multiple Lines]
[image: After running QChainage points on original lines]

Comment: Have you had a look at `points along lines` in the toolbox? If so, how does it not suit your needs?

Comment: @Erik Yes this was one of the first tools to try. It did not work as expected and that's how I ended up doing some research and finding the post above, which suggested using additional plugins.